# How to pass variable from java file to IN clause of a query in xml file

Tags: java, xml

For example,

In java file,

```
String[] arrayTest= {"a", "b", "c"};
String strTest = "";
for (String test: arrayTest) {
    strTest = strTest + ", " + test;
}
strTest = strTest.substring(1);
```

In xml file,  pass the variable to IN clause like:

```
Where test in (#strTest#)
```

But it did not work.

Comment: select * is not XML, it's SQL.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: From the above comment, it seems the question was originally about SQL. But it's been edited, and it now gives no clue at all as to what query language it's talking about. Could be SQL, could be XQuery, could be XPath. Unanswerable in this form, downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean you are storing this SQL query in an XML file with some other XML data? You could use StringBuilder and a for loop to build up the required SQL query as a String.

Comment: That's pretty bad advice: it lays you open to code injection. SQL can be parameterized using "?" as a place-holder for variables.